# Calculate area of truncated torus

Tags: geometry

Good morning, I need to calculate the area of a section of a torus, at a certain position, as you can see in the image below:

[image]

Anyone can help me?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Certainly someone will help you if you show what you have done so far, where you have stuck. But posting a picture alone, without any explanation, could result in your question being downvoted (as it happened twice in 6 minutes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sections of a torus by a plane parallel to the revolution axis are known as Cassini's ovals. Wolfram gives the formula for the area, in terms of an elliptic integral: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/CassiniOvals.html

The special case of a plane tangent to the inner equator is a lemniscate, and the formula simplifies.